Get image alt name with event.target.innerHTML
I use the following attribute on a page to return the inner element clicked in a certain div.
onclick="alert(event.target.innerHTML)";

It properly returns the name if I click on a heading element, but it returns nothing if clicked on an image element.
How can I return the alt name of the image clicked?
Heading element:

Image element:


Try event.currentTarget. This is a guess though, without seeing your actual HTML structure

Why not directly use the attribute you want to read, instead of using the whole HTML as a string?

Well as @Rory McCrossan mentioned in their comment that it is hard to guess the actual code flow/scenario without your HTML structure, so I have created a minimal re-production of the scenario which I understood from your post. I assume you want to get innerHTML for all the other elements, but for img you want the alt attribute. So here is a refactored function for that to check the target element and then alert accordingly.
I provided "image" as an alt to my img element


function onElementClick(e) {
  const elem = event.target;
  const message = elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'img' ? elem.alt : elem.innerHTML;
  window.alert(message);
}
div:hover,
img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
<html>

<body>
    <div onclick="onElementClick(this)">Some Element</div>
    <div>
        <h1 onclick="onElementClick(this)">Some Heading</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1687892170417-f9a11a402ef7?w=500&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OXx8Y29tcHV0ZXJ8ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D"
            alt="image" width="200" height="auto" onclick="onElementClick(this)" />
    </div>
</body>

</html>




Rather than using innerHTML, you simply want to get the alt property instead when using this code on images. Obviously if they don't have an alt attribute set this'll return undefined, so you can't use this on headers etc.
onclick="alert(event.target.alt)" should work for you
(also I noticed you had a trailing semicolon in your code snippet, you need to remove that)
